# Syncfusion data grid can't display photo

Tags: c#, ios, datagrid, syncfusion

I have an employee datable that I would like to show in a syncfusion iOS data grid. One of the fields in the datable is a photo field that contains the employees' photo. My problem is that this photo column in the grid  shows only `System.Byte[]`, not the photo.

I guess I must somehow format the column in the `GridAutoGeneratingColumns` event but I'm not reaching there. I'm using `xamarin.ios and C#, and would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement can be achieved in two ways. If you are using the older version of SfDataGrid, you can use the GridTextColumn.UserCellType property to load image in SfDataGrid, else you can update the SfDataGrid to the latest version (15.2.0.40) and use the GridImageColumn to load the image in SfDataGrid. The build action of the image should be either EmbeddedResource or BundleResource.

Please refer the below code example to load the image using GridTextColumn.UserCellType property.

```
GridTextColumn customerImageColumn = new GridTextColumn();
customerImageColumn.UserCellType = typeof(GridImageCell);
customerImageColumn.MappingName = "CustomerImage";
customerImageColumn.HeaderText = "Image";

//GridImageCell.cs
public class GridImageCell : GridCell
    {
        private UIImageView imageview;
        CoreGraphics.CGRect framespec = new CoreGraphics.CGRect();

        public GridImageCell()
        {
            imageview = new UIImageView();
            this.CanRenderUnLoad = false;
        }

        protected override void UnLoad()
        {
            this.RemoveFromSuperview();
        }

        public override void LayoutSubviews()
        {
            base.LayoutSubviews();
            if (imageview.Superview == null)
            {
                this.AddSubview(imageview);
                framespec = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(20, 3, 60, (nfloat)DataColumn.Renderer.DataGrid.RowHeight - 5);
            }

            imageview.Frame = framespec;
            imageview.Image = (UIImage)DataColumn.RowData.GetType().GetProperty("CustomerImage").GetValue(DataColumn.RowData);
        }
}
```

Please refer the below code example to load the image using GridImageColumn.

```
GridImageColumn customerImageColumn = new GridImageColumn();
customerImageColumn.MappingName = "CustomerImage";
customerImageColumn.HeaderText = "Image";

// Model class - The type of the “CustomerImage” should be UIImage
public UIImage CustomerImage  
{
    get
    {
        return customerImage;
    }
    set
    {
        customerImage = value;
    }
}

// Repository class – the image should be set to the “CustomerImage” property as highlighted
public List<OrderInfo> GetBankDetails(int count)
{
    List<OrderInfo> bankDetails = new List<OrderInfo>();

    for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++)
    {
        var ord = new OrderInfo()
        {
            CustomerID = i,
            BranchNo = BranchNo[random.Next(15)],
            Current = CurrentBalance[random.Next(15)],
            Savings = Savings[random.Next(15)],
            CustomerName = Customers[random.Next(15)],
            BalanceScale = random.Next(1, 100),
            IsOpen = ((i % random.Next(1, 10) > 2) ? true : false),
            CustomerImage = Imagehelper.ToUIImage(new ImageMapStream(LoadResource("Image1.png").ToArray())),
            Transactions = random.Next(80)
        };
        bankDetails.Add(ord);
    }
    return bankDetails;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help